# Get Timezone Information in VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, timezone, dst

I would like to determine a time offset to GMT/UTC (including daylight saving time) for different countries at a specific date in VBA. Any ideas?

EDIT (from self-answer):

Thank you 0xA3. I quickly read-over the linked page. I assume that you can only get the offset to GMT for the local where windows is running:

```
ConvertLocalToGMT    
DaylightTime  
GetLocalTimeFromGMT          
LocalOffsetFromGMT
SystemTimeToVBTime
LocalOffsetFromGMT
```

In Java you can do the following:

```
TimeZone bucharestTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Bucharest");
    bucharestTimeZone.getOffset(new Date().getTime());

Calendar nowInBucharest = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Bucharest"));
    nowInBucharest.setTime(new Date());
    System.out.println("Bucharest: " + nowInBucharest.get(Calendar.HOUR) + ":" + nowInBucharest.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

This means I can get the offset for different countries (timezones) and I thus can also get the actual time lets say in bucharest. Can I do this in VBA?

Answer (score 14):

VBA doesn't offer functions to do that, but the Windows API does. Luckily you can use all those functionality from VBA as well. This page describes how to do it: **[Time Zones & Daylight Savings Time](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx)**

---

**Edit: Added Code**

For the posterity sake, I've added the complete code from Guru Chip's page, as usable in 32-bit Office VBA. (64-bit modification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489651/8112776))

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modTimeZones
' By Chip Pearson, used with permission from www.cpearson.com
' Date: 2-April-2008
' Page Specific URL: www.cpearson.com/Excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx
'
' This module contains functions related to time zones and GMT times.
'   Terms:
'   -------------------------
'   GMT = Greenwich Mean Time. Many applications use the term
'       UTC (Universal Coordinated Time). GMT and UTC are
'       interchangable in meaning,
'   Local Time = The local "wall clock" time of day, that time that
'       you would set a clock to.
'   DST = Daylight Savings Time

'   Functions In This Module:
'   -------------------------
'       ConvertLocalToGMT
'           Converts a local time to GMT. Optionally adjusts for DST.
'       DaylightTime
'           Returns a value indicating (1) DST is in effect, (2) DST is
'           not in effect, or (3) Windows cannot determine whether DST is
'           in effect.
'       GetLocalTimeFromGMT
'           Converts a GMT Time to a Local Time, optionally adjusting for DST.
'       LocalOffsetFromGMT
'           Returns the number of hours/minutes between the local time &GMT,
'           optionally adjusting for DST.
'       SystemTimeToVBTime
'           Converts a SYSTEMTIME structure to a valid VB/VBA date.
'       LocalOffsetFromGMT
'           Returns the number of minutes or hours that are to be added to
'           the local time to get GMT. Optionally adjusts for DST.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

' Required Types
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Public Enum TIME_ZONE
    TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID = 0
    TIME_ZONE_STANDARD = 1
    TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT = 2
End Enum

' Required Windows API Declares
Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long

Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)

Function ConvertLocalToGMT(Optional LocalTime As Date, _
    Optional AdjustForDST As Boolean = False) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ConvertLocalToGMT
' This converts a local time to GMT. If LocalTime is present, that local
' time is converted to GMT. If LocalTime is omitted, the current time is
' converted from local to GMT. If AdjustForDST is Fasle, no adjustments
' are made to accomodate DST. If AdjustForDST is True, and DST is
' in effect, the time is adjusted for DST by adding
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim T As Date
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    Dim GMT As Date

    If LocalTime <= 0 Then
        T = Now
    Else
        T = LocalTime
    End If
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
    If AdjustForDST = True Then
        GMT = T + TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0) + _
                IIf(DST=TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT,TimeSerial(0, TZI.DaylightBias,0),0)
    Else
        GMT = T + TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0)
    End If
    ConvertLocalToGMT = GMT
End Function

Function GetLocalTimeFromGMT(Optional StartTime As Date) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' GetLocalTimeFromGMT
' This returns the Local Time from a GMT time. If StartDate is present and
' greater than 0, it is assumed to be the GMT from which we will calculate
' Local Time. If StartTime is 0 or omitted, it is assumed to be the GMT
' local time.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim GMT As Date
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    Dim LocalTime As Date

    If StartTime <= 0 Then
        GMT = Now
    Else
        GMT = StartTime
    End If
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
    LocalTime = GMT - TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0) + _
            IIf(DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT, TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), 0)
    GetLocalTimeFromGMT = LocalTime
End Function

Function SystemTimeToVBTime(SysTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SystemTimeToVBTime
' This converts a SYSTEMTIME structure to a VB/VBA date value.
' It assumes SysTime is valid -- no error checking is done.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    With SysTime
        SystemTimeToVBTime = DateSerial(.wYear, .wMonth, .wDay) + _
                TimeSerial(.wHour, .wMinute, .wSecond)
    End With
End Function

Function LocalOffsetFromGMT(Optional AsHours As Boolean = False, _
    Optional AdjustForDST As Boolean = False) As Long
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' LocalOffsetFromGMT
' This returns the amount of time in minutes (if AsHours is omitted or
' false) or hours (if AsHours is True) that should be added to the
' local time to get GMT. If AdjustForDST is missing or false,
' the unmodified difference is returned. (e.g., Kansas City to London
' is 6 hours normally, 5 hours during DST. If AdjustForDST is False,
' the resultif 6 hours. If AdjustForDST is True, the result is 5 hours
' if DST is in effect.)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim TBias As Long
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)

    If DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT Then
        If AdjustForDST = True Then
            TBias = TZI.Bias + TZI.DaylightBias
        Else
            TBias = TZI.Bias
        End If
    Else
        TBias = TZI.Bias
    End If
    If AsHours = True Then
        TBias = TBias / 60
    End If

    LocalOffsetFromGMT = TBias
End Function

Function DaylightTime() As TIME_ZONE
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' DaylightTime
' Returns a value indicating whether the current date is
' in Daylight Time, Standard Time, or that Windows cannot
' deterimine the time status. The result is a member or
' the TIME_ZONE enum.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
    DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
    DaylightTime = DST
End Function
```

Comment: +1 But I suggest pasting (or writing, if you think copyright problems may arise)  the relevant code here too. If the source site goes down, it will stay here for future reference

Comment: @belisarius: Good point, hopefully me or someone else will have the time to do so later ;-)

Comment: I added the code as an additional answer to the question.  Although I had to make a change to the Declare statements to allow it work properly with Office 64 bit.

Comment: Chip Pearson's [site](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx)'s been down for 2 days... I feel incomplete.  :-(

Comment: @ashleedawg: You can access the archive version here: https://web.archive.org/web/20171017030345/http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

Comment: @DirkVollmar - I guess this was the answer I was looking at when I found out what happened with Chip.   The good news is the site was restored, and will remain up indefinitely (thanks to [Greg Truby](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/members/greg-truby.html) and Chip's family.)

Answer (score 8):

Please be aware of little trap in the solution.

The GetTimeZoneInformation() call returns DST info about the **current time**, but the converted date might be from the period with the different DST setting - thus converting January date in August would apply the current Bias, thus yielding the GMT date 1 hour less than the correct one (**SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime** seems to be a better fit - untested yet)

The same applies when the date is from another year - when DST rules might have been different. **GetTimeZoneInformationForYear** should handle changes in different years. I'll put a code sample here once completed.

It also seems Windows does not provide a reliable way to get 3 letter abbreviation of the timezone (Excel 2013 supports zzz in Format() - not tested).

*Edit 16.04.2015*: IntArrayToString() removed as it is already present in modWorksheetFunctions.bas referenced in below mentioned cpearson.com articles.

Adding code to convert using timezone active at the time of the converted date (this issue is not addressed on cpearson.com). Error handling is not included for brevity.

```
Private Type DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION_VB
    Bias As Long
    StandardName As String
    StandardDate As Date
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName As String
    DaylightDate As Date
    DaylightBias As Long
    TimeZoneKeyName As String
    DynamicDaylightTimeDisabled As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformationForYear Lib "kernel32" ( _
    wYear As Integer, _
    lpDynamicTimeZoneInformation As DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, _
    lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION _
) As Long

Private Declare Function GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" ( _
    pTimeZoneInformation As DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION _
) As Long

Private Declare Function TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTimeEx Lib "kernel32" ( _
    lpDynamicTimeZoneInformation As DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION, _
    lpLocalTime As SYSTEMTIME, _
    lpUniversalTime As SYSTEMTIME _
) As Long

Function LocalSerialTimeToGmt(lpDateLocal As Date) As Date
    Dim retval As Boolean, lpDateGmt As Date, lpSystemTimeLocal As SYSTEMTIME, lpSystemTimeGmt As SYSTEMTIME
    Dim lpDTZI As DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION 

    retval = SerialTimeToSystemTime(lpDateLocal, lpSystemTimeLocal)
    retval = GetDynamicTimeZoneInformation(lpDTZI)
    retval = TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTimeEx(lpDTZI, lpSystemTimeLocal, lpSystemTimeGmt)
    lpDateGmt = SystemTimeToSerialTime(lpSystemTimeGmt)
    LocalSerialTimeToGmt = lpDateGmt
End Function
```

There are 2 ways to achieve offset:

1. subtract local date and converted gmt date:

   `offset = (lpDateLocal - lpDateGmt)*24*60`
2. get TZI for specific year and calculate:

   `dst = GetTimeZoneInformationForYear(Year(lpDateLocal), lpDTZI, lpTZI)
   offset = lpTZI.Bias + IIf(lpDateLocal >= SystemTimeToSerialTime(lpTZI.DaylightDate) And lpDateLocal < SystemTimeToSerialTime(lpTZI.StandardDate), lpTZI.DaylightBias, lpTZI.StandardBias)`

Caveat: For some reason, values populated in lpTZI here do not contain the year information, so you need to set the year in lpTZI.DaylightDate and lpTZI.StandardDate.

Comment: Worth noting that trap: there's a 7-day period in every year when London and New York are in different daylight-saving modes. If you're importing timestamped data from applications across these two locations, you *will* encounter this trap during that period.

Comment: What surprises me the most, is that there was no-one reporting the same problem using VBA and even great cpearson scripts dont handle that (and even processing 6 months old data in your own timezone you have to stumble across this).

Comment: I discovered this (and thank you for it!), and I was trying to use the TZI for comparing dates: *BUT YOU CAN'T RELIABLY DO THIS* see: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110311-00/?p=11243, and the official docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/ns-timezoneapi-dynamic_time_zone_information

Turns out, the "Day" component of the TZI (if year is not specified) is the RELATIVE week and day...so you'll need to do some more fancy footwork to compare.

You need to use your #1 method otherwise.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the code that is referenced in the answer by 0xA3.  I had to change the declare statements to allow it run properly in Office 64bit but I haven't been able to test again in Office 32bit. For my use I was trying to create ISO 8601 dates with timezone information. So i used this function for that.

```
Public Function ConvertToIsoTime(myDate As Date, includeTimezone As Boolean) As String

    If Not includeTimezone Then
        ConvertToIsoTime = Format(myDate, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")
    Else
        Dim minOffsetLong As Long
        Dim hourOffset As Integer
        Dim minOffset As Integer
        Dim formatStr As String
        Dim hourOffsetStr As String

        minOffsetLong = LocalOffsetFromGMT(False, True) * -1
        hourOffset = minOffsetLong \ 60
        minOffset = minOffsetLong Mod 60

        If hourOffset >= 0 Then
            hourOffsetStr = "+" + CStr(Format(hourOffset, "00"))
        Else
            hourOffsetStr = CStr(Format(hourOffset, "00"))
        End If

        formatStr = "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss" + hourOffsetStr + ":" + CStr(Format(minOffset, "00"))
        ConvertToIsoTime = Format(myDate, formatStr)


    End If

End Function
```

The code below came from http://www.cpearson.com/excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modTimeZones
' By Chip Pearson, chip@cpearson.com, www.cpearson.com
' Date: 2-April-2008
' Page Specific URL: www.cpearson.com/Excel/TimeZoneAndDaylightTime.aspx
'
' This module contains functions related to time zones and GMT times.
'   Terms:
'   -------------------------
'   GMT = Greenwich Mean Time. Many applications use the term
'       UTC (Universal Coordinated Time). GMT and UTC are
'       interchangable in meaning,
'   Local Time = The local "wall clock" time of day, that time that
'       you would set a clock to.
'   DST = Daylight Savings Time

'   Functions In This Module:
'   -------------------------
'       ConvertLocalToGMT
'           Converts a local time to GMT. Optionally adjusts for DST.
'       DaylightTime
'           Returns a value indicating (1) DST is in effect, (2) DST is
'           not in effect, or (3) Windows cannot determine whether DST is
'           in effect.
'       GetLocalTimeFromGMT
'           Converts a GMT Time to a Local Time, optionally adjusting for DST.
'       LocalOffsetFromGMT
'           Returns the number of hours or minutes between the local time and GMT,
'           optionally adjusting for DST.
'       SystemTimeToVBTime
'           Converts a SYSTEMTIME structure to a valid VB/VBA date.
'       LocalOffsetFromGMT
'           Returns the number of minutes or hours that are to be added to
'           the local time to get GMT. Optionally adjusts for DST.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''


'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Required Types
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Private Type SYSTEMTIME
    wYear As Integer
    wMonth As Integer
    wDayOfWeek As Integer
    wDay As Integer
    wHour As Integer
    wMinute As Integer
    wSecond As Integer
    wMilliseconds As Integer
End Type

Private Type TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
    Bias As Long
    StandardName(0 To 31) As Integer
    StandardDate As SYSTEMTIME
    StandardBias As Long
    DaylightName(0 To 31) As Integer
    DaylightDate As SYSTEMTIME
    DaylightBias As Long
End Type

Public Enum TIME_ZONE
    TIME_ZONE_ID_INVALID = 0
    TIME_ZONE_STANDARD = 1
    TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT = 2
End Enum

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Required Windows API Declares
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function GetTimeZoneInformation Lib "kernel32" _
    (lpTimeZoneInformation As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION) As Long
#End If

#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" _
        (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
#Else
    Private Declare Sub GetSystemTime Lib "kernel32" _
        (lpSystemTime As SYSTEMTIME)
#End If




Function ConvertLocalToGMT(Optional LocalTime As Date, _
    Optional AdjustForDST As Boolean = False) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ConvertLocalToGMT
' This converts a local time to GMT. If LocalTime is present, that local
' time is converted to GMT. If LocalTime is omitted, the current time is
' converted from local to GMT. If AdjustForDST is Fasle, no adjustments
' are made to accomodate DST. If AdjustForDST is True, and DST is
' in effect, the time is adjusted for DST by adding
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim T As Date
Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
Dim GMT As Date

If LocalTime <= 0 Then
    T = Now
Else
    T = LocalTime
End If
DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
If AdjustForDST = True Then
    GMT = T + TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0) + _
            IIf(DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT, TimeSerial(0, TZI.DaylightBias, 0), 0)
Else
    GMT = T + TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0)
End If
ConvertLocalToGMT = GMT

End Function


Function GetLocalTimeFromGMT(Optional StartTime As Date) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' GetLocalTimeFromGMT
' This returns the Local Time from a GMT time. If StartDate is present and
' greater than 0, it is assumed to be the GMT from which we will calculate
' Local Time. If StartTime is 0 or omitted, it is assumed to be the GMT
' local time.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim GMT As Date
Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
Dim LocalTime As Date

If StartTime <= 0 Then
    GMT = Now
Else
    GMT = StartTime
End If
DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
LocalTime = GMT - TimeSerial(0, TZI.Bias, 0) + _
        IIf(DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT, TimeSerial(1, 0, 0), 0)
GetLocalTimeFromGMT = LocalTime

End Function

Function SystemTimeToVBTime(SysTime As SYSTEMTIME) As Date
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' SystemTimeToVBTime
' This converts a SYSTEMTIME structure to a VB/VBA date value.
' It assumes SysTime is valid -- no error checking is done.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
With SysTime
    SystemTimeToVBTime = DateSerial(.wYear, .wMonth, .wDay) + _
            TimeSerial(.wHour, .wMinute, .wSecond)
End With

End Function

Function LocalOffsetFromGMT(Optional AsHours As Boolean = False, _
    Optional AdjustForDST As Boolean = False) As Long
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' LocalOffsetFromGMT
' This returns the amount of time in minutes (if AsHours is omitted or
' false) or hours (if AsHours is True) that should be added to the
' local time to get GMT. If AdjustForDST is missing or false,
' the unmodified difference is returned. (e.g., Kansas City to London
' is 6 hours normally, 5 hours during DST. If AdjustForDST is False,
' the resultif 6 hours. If AdjustForDST is True, the result is 5 hours
' if DST is in effect.)
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim TBias As Long
Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)

If DST = TIME_ZONE_DAYLIGHT Then
    If AdjustForDST = True Then
        TBias = TZI.Bias + TZI.DaylightBias
    Else
        TBias = TZI.Bias
    End If
Else
    TBias = TZI.Bias
End If
If AsHours = True Then
    TBias = TBias / 60
End If

LocalOffsetFromGMT = TBias

End Function

Function DaylightTime() As TIME_ZONE
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' DaylightTime
' Returns a value indicating whether the current date is
' in Daylight Time, Standard Time, or that Windows cannot
' deterimine the time status. The result is a member or
' the TIME_ZONE enum.
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim TZI As TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION
Dim DST As TIME_ZONE
DST = GetTimeZoneInformation(TZI)
DaylightTime = DST
End Function
```

Answer (score 7):

I recommend to create an Outlook object and use the in-built method **ConvertTime**: https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/timezones-converttime-method-outlook

Super easy, super save and just a few lines of code

> This example converts the inputTime from UTC to CET:
>
> As a source/destination time zone you can use all time zones you can find
>   in your registry under: 
>   **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Time Zones/**
>
> ```
> Dim OutlookApp As Object
> Dim TZones As TimeZones
> Dim convertedTime As Date
> Dim inputTime As Date
> Dim sourceTZ As TimeZone
> Dim destTZ As TimeZone
> Dim secNum as Integer
> Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
> Set TZones = OutlookApp.TimeZones
> Set sourceTZ = TZones.Item("UTC")
> Set destTZ = TZones.Item("W. Europe Standard Time")
> inputTime = Now
> Debug.Print "GMT: " & inputTime
> '' the outlook rounds the seconds to the nearest minute
> '' thus, we store the seconds, convert the truncated time and add them later 
> secNum = Second(inputTime)
> inputTime = DateAdd("s",-secNum, inputTime)
> convertedTime = TZones.ConvertTime(inputTime, sourceTZ, destTZ)
> convertedTime = DateAdd("s",secNum, convertedTime)
> Debug.Print "CET: " & convertedTime
> ```

*PS: if you often have to use the method, I recommend to declare the Outlook object outside of your sub/function. Create it once and keep it alive.*

Comment: This looks very interesting, but how do you provide the source and destination Timezones ? Could you evenyually provide a small sample ? Thx

Comment: thx. However the provided code does not seem to compile. ConvertTime requires a `TimeZone` object for the 2d and 3d parameters, not a string.

Comment: @PatrickHonorez please refresh the page to see the correct code

Comment: SUPER ! Not only does it work, but is seems to know that we are now on daylight saving time (DST). So if I want to convert - say - time from Boston to LUX, this should work all year long, as long as I calculate it on the same day the event happens, right ?

Comment: you don't even need to be on the same day of the event! this works also for historical dates when the DST differs from the current date!!!! that is the great advantage of using Outlook's in-build method. Of cause Outlook's calendar needs to be able to deal with DST :-) strange that no one came up with this idea yet....

Comment: You can also use `Set OutlookApp = GetObject(,"Outlook.Application")` to avoid loading another instance of Outlook

Comment: Interesting to note that the process seems to strip the seconds

Comment: @PatrickHonorez, thanks for highlighting the second truncation. I adjusted the above example with an easy workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Based on Julian Hess excellent recommendation to use Outlook capabilities, I have build this module, which works with Access and Excel.

```
Option Explicit

'mTimeZones by Patrick Honorez --- www.idevlop.com
'with the precious help of Julian Hess https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510712/78522
'You can reuse but please let all the original comments including this one.

'This modules uses late binding and therefore should not require an explicit reference to Outlook,
'however Outlook must be properly installed and configured on the machine using this module
'Module works with Excel and Access

Private oOutl As Object 'keep Outlook reference active, to save time in recurring calls
Private oOutlTimeZones As Object 'keep Outlook reference active, to save time in recurring calls
' seems to drop the reference if use previous scheme of returning boolean
' returning the actual object is more correct in any case
Private Function GetOutlookTimeZones() As Object
    If oOutl Is Nothing Or oOutlTimeZones Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "~"
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutl = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If Err.Number Then
            Err.Clear
            Set oOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If
        Set oOutlTimeZones = oOutl.TimeZones
    End If
    Set GetOutlookTimeZones = oOutlTimeZones
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function ConvertTime(DT As Date, Optional TZfrom As String = "Central Standard Time", _
                                 Optional TZto As String = "W. Europe Standard Time") As Date
'convert datetime with hour from Source time zone to Target time zone
'valid Source & Target time zones can be found in your registry under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Time Zones/
'this version using Outlook, properly handles Dailight Saving Times, including for past and future dates
'it includes a fix for the fact that ConvertTime seems to strip the seconds
'krammy85 2019-01-25 Edit: Outlook rounds minutes when it strips seconds, so modified code to strip seconds (without rounding) prior to running Outlook's ConvertTime.
    Dim sourceTZ As Object
    Dim destTZ As Object
    Dim seconds As Single
    Dim DT_SecondsStripped As Date
    Dim oOutlTimeZones As Object: Set oOutlTimeZones = GetOutlookTimeZones()
    If Not (oOutlTimeZones Is Nothing) Then
        'fix for ConvertTime stripping the seconds
        seconds = Second(DT) / 86400    'save the seconds as DateTime (86400 = 24*60*60)
        DT_SecondsStripped = DT - seconds
        Set sourceTZ = oOutlTimeZones.Item(TZfrom)
        Set destTZ = oOutlTimeZones.Item(TZto)
        ConvertTime = oOutlTimeZones.ConvertTime(DT_SecondsStripped, sourceTZ, destTZ) + seconds    'add the stripped seconds
    End If
End Function

' returns number of minutes ahead of UTC (positive number) or behind
Function GetOffsetAt(DT As Date, TZfrom As String) As Long
    Dim utc_DT As Date: utc_DT = ConvertTime(DT, TZfrom, "UTC")
    GetOffsetAt = DateDiff("n", utc_DT, DT)
End Function

Sub test_ConvertTime()
    Dim t As Date: t = #8/23/2017 6:15:05 AM#
    Debug.Print t, ConvertTime(t), Format(t - ConvertTime(t), "h")
    Debug.Print t, ConvertTime(t, "Central Standard Time", "W. Europe Standard Time"), Format(t - ConvertTime(t), "h")
End Sub

Sub test_DumpTZs()
    Dim TZ As Object: For Each TZ In GetOutlookTimeZones()
        Debug.Print "TZ:", TZ.Id, TZ.Name
    Next TZ
End Sub
```

Comment: Your `GetOutLook` function could just use `Set oOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` - only one instance of Outlook can be open at a time so in this instance `CreateObject` gets the object if it's already open.... just got to find the documentation to back my claim up now.

Comment: Looks like a good remark. I used that code for Excel and thought it coulld save a few msec with Outlook, but indeed I think you're right: one can only have one instance of Outlook running. Quite easy to test, but now I have a contract in a place where they use....Lotus Notes 8-((

Comment: This is great – it should probably be the top-ranked answer! It appears from the comments that both answers based on the Windows API are buggy, and they involve a lot more code. I’m much more comfortable with a solution where all the actual arithmetic is done by Outlook. I’m just going to edit your answer to add a reference to the list of magic strings that are valid timezones. Thank you!

Comment: I've also added a `GetOffsetAt`, useful for instance in calculating the right offset for ISO8601 timestamps.

Comment: Nice one! You can also get your local timezone with that object:
`Debug.Print oOutlTimeZones.CurrentTimeZone.id`

Answer (score 0):

While Outlook may provide a (slow) shortcut to the time zone information, you can go the direct route, but it takes a lot of code for a generic solution - much more than posted above and way too much to post here, partly because some information is localised.

A core function from my project [VBA.Timezone-Windows](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Timezone-Windows) is this:

```vb
' Required references:
'   Windows Script Host Object Model
'
' 2019-12-14. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Private Function GetRegistryTimezoneItems( _
    Optional ByRef DynamicDstYear As Integer) _
    As TimezoneEntry()

    Const Component     As String = "winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\default:StdRegProv"
    Const DefKey        As Long = HKeyLocalMachine
    Const HKey          As String = "HKLM"
    Const SubKeyPath    As String = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones"
    Const DstPath       As String = "Dynamic DST"

    Const DisplayKey    As String = "Display"
    Const DaylightKey   As String = "Dlt"
    Const StandardKey   As String = "Std"
    Const MuiDisplayKey As String = "MUI_Display"
    Const MuiDltKey     As String = "MUI_Dlt"
    Const MuiStdKey     As String = "MUI_Std"
    Const TziKey        As String = "TZI"
    Const FirstEntryKey As String = "FirstEntry"
    Const LastEntryKey  As String = "LastEntry"
   
    Dim SWbemServices   As Object
    Dim WshShell        As WshShell
   
    Dim SubKey          As Variant
    Dim Names           As Variant
    Dim NameKeys        As Variant
   
    Dim Display         As String
    Dim DisplayUtc      As String
    Dim Name            As Variant
    Dim DstEntry        As Variant
    Dim Mui             As Integer
    Dim BiasLabel       As String
    Dim Bias            As Long
    Dim Locations       As String
    Dim TziDetails      As Variant
    Dim TzItems()       As TimezoneEntry
    Dim TzItem          As TimezoneEntry
    Dim Index           As Long
    Dim SubIndex        As Long
    Dim Value           As String
    Dim LBoundItems     As Long
    Dim UBoundItems     As Long
   
    Dim TziInformation  As RegTziFormat

    ' The call is either for another year, or
    ' more than one day has passed since the last call.
    Set SWbemServices = GetObject(Component)
    Set WshShell = New WshShell

    SWbemServices.EnumKey DefKey, SubKeyPath, Names
    ' Retrieve all timezones' base data.
    LBoundItems = LBound(Names)
    UBoundItems = UBound(Names)
    ReDim TzItems(LBoundItems To UBoundItems)
   
    For Index = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
        ' Assemble paths and look up key values.
        SubKey = Names(Index)
       
        ' Invariant name of timezone.
        TzItem.Name = SubKey
       
        ' MUI of the timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, MuiDisplayKey), "\")
        Value = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
        Mui = Val(Split(Value, ",")(1))
        TzItem.Mui = Mui
        ' MUI of the standard timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, MuiStdKey), "\")
        Value = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
        Mui = Val(Split(Value, ",")(1))
        TzItem.MuiStandard = Mui
        ' MUI of the DST timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, MuiDltKey), "\")
        Value = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
        Mui = Val(Split(Value, ",")(1))
        TzItem.MuiDaylight = Mui
       
        ' Localised description of the timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, DisplayKey), "\")
        Display = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
        ' Extract the first part, cleaned like "UTC+08:30".
        DisplayUtc = Mid(Split(Display, ")", 2)(0) & "+00:00", 2, 9)
        ' Extract the offset part of first part, like "+08:30".
        BiasLabel = Mid(Split(Display, ")", 2)(0) & "+00:00", 5, 6)
        ' Convert the offset part of the first part to a bias value (signed integer minutes).
        Bias = -Val(Left(BiasLabel, 1) & Str(CDbl(CDate(Mid(BiasLabel, 2))) * 24 * 60))
        ' Extract the last part, holding the location(s).
        Locations = Split(Display, " ", 2)(1)
        TzItem.Bias = Bias
        TzItem.Utc = DisplayUtc
        TzItem.Locations = Locations
       
        ' Localised name of the standard timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, StandardKey), "\")
        TzItem.ZoneStandard = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
        ' Localised name of the DST timezone.
        Name = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, DaylightKey), "\")
        TzItem.ZoneDaylight = WshShell.RegRead(Name)
       
        ' TZI details.
        SWbemServices.GetBinaryValue DefKey, Join(Array(SubKeyPath, SubKey), "\"), TziKey, TziDetails
        FillRegTziFormat TziDetails, TziInformation
        TzItem.Tzi = TziInformation
        ' Default Dynamic DST range.
        TzItem.FirstEntry = Null
        TzItem.LastEntry = Null
       
        ' Check for Dynamic DST info.
        SWbemServices.EnumKey DefKey, Join(Array(SubKeyPath, SubKey), "\"), NameKeys
        If IsArray(NameKeys) Then
            ' This timezone has subkeys. Check if Dynamic DST is present.
            For SubIndex = LBound(NameKeys) To UBound(NameKeys)
                If NameKeys(SubIndex) = DstPath Then
                    ' Dynamic DST details found.
                    ' Record first and last entry.
                    DstEntry = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, DstPath, FirstEntryKey), "\")
                    Value = WshShell.RegRead(DstEntry)
                    TzItem.FirstEntry = Value
                    DstEntry = Join(Array(HKey, SubKeyPath, SubKey, DstPath, LastEntryKey), "\")
                    Value = WshShell.RegRead(DstEntry)
                    TzItem.LastEntry = Value
                   
                    If DynamicDstYear >= TzItems(Index).FirstEntry And _
                        DynamicDstYear <= TzItems(Index).LastEntry Then
                        ' Replace default TZI details with those from the dynamic DST.
                        DstEntry = Join(Array(SubKeyPath, SubKey, DstPath), "\")
                        SWbemServices.GetBinaryValue DefKey, Join(Array(SubKeyPath, SubKey), "\"), , CStr(DynamicDstYear), TziDetails
                        FillRegTziFormat TziDetails, TziInformation
                        TzItem.Tzi = TziInformation
                    Else
                        ' Dynamic DST year was not found.
                        ' Return current year.
                        DynamicDstYear = Year(Date)
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        End If
        TzItems(Index) = TzItem
    Next
   
    GetRegistryTimezoneItems = TzItems
   
End Function
```

The project is supported by two articles:

[Time Zones, Windows, and VBA - Part 1](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33988/Time-Zones-Windows-and-VBA-Part-1.html)

[Time Zones, Windows, and Microsoft Office - Part 2](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/33997/Time-Zones-Windows-and-Microsoft-Office-Part-2.html)

including demos for Access and Excel.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Following are several functions that may be helpful, by comparing the returned values of **IsDST** with **CheckDST** and then adjusting the timezone date/time value accordingly.  For example:

```
Dim SomeDateTime As Date 'Or Double

If IsDST Then
    'Is currently DST, so add an hour if the date/time to be checked includes a standard-time date.
    
    If Not CheckDST(SomeDateTime) Then SomeDateTime = SomeDateTime + TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
Else
    'Is not currently DST, so subtract an hour if the date/time to be checked includes a DST date.
    
    If CheckDST(SomeDateTime) Then SomeDateTime = SomeDateTime - TimeSerial(1, 0, 0)
End If
```

**CheckDST**: Full-featured version. Returns True if Daylight Savings Time (or British Summer Time) applies to a specified date (in an optionally specified locale); otherwise returns False. Handles all US DST (and UK BST) system variations back to 1966, including President Nixon's "Emergency Daylight Saving Time Energy Conservation Act" of 1973 and Harold Wilson's "British Standard Time" experiment, October 27, 1968 to October 31, 1971.

**CheckDST_UK1972**: Simplified version. Returns True if the UK British Summer Time applies to a specified date, based on the BST system as it has been defined since 1972; otherwise returns False.

**CheckDST_US2007**: Simplified version. Returns True if the US Federal Daylight Savings Time applies to a specified date, based on the DST system established in 2007; otherwise returns False.

**IsDST**: Returns True if Daylight Savings Time is *currently* in effect (in the optionally specified locale); otherwise returns False.

**NthDayOfWeekDate**: Returns the Date of a specified Nth instance of a specified day-of-week in a specified month.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CheckDST(ChkDate As Variant, Optional Locale As String = "USA") As Boolean
    '
    'Returns True if Daylight Savings Time applies to the specified date (in the optionally specified locale);
    'otherwise returns False.  Note that this function handles all dates back to 1/1/1966.  For dates prior to
    'that, an error message is displayed due to the difficulty of handling the highly inconsistent use of DST in
    'prior years, across various locales.
    '
    'PARAMETERS:
    '
    '   ChkDate     The date to be checked for DST status.  The data-type of the calling code's argument can
    '               be either Date or Double.
    '
    '   Locale      The geographic locale within which that locale's DST rules are to be applied. Values:
    '                   "AZ"    - DST hasn't applied to Arizona since 1967.
    '                   "NN"    - DST has applied in the Navajo Nation of northeastern Arizona.
    '                   "AS"    - DST has never applied in American Samoa (since WWII).
    '                   "GU"    -   "   Guam.
    '                   "HI"    -   "   Hawaii.
    '                   "MP"    -   "   Northern Marina Islands.
    '                   "PR"    -   "   Puerto Rico.
    '                   "VI"    -   "   Virgin Islands.
    '                   "UK"    - British Summer Time (BST) has been applied since the end of WWII (1945), from
    '                             the last Sunday of March through the last Sunday of October, with one exception
    '                             period from 1968 through 1971 in which it applied all year long (see details
    '                             below).
    '                   "USA"   - All other states in the US, for which the federal DST rules have applied.
    '                             Correctly handles President Nixon's "Emergency Daylight Saving Time Energy
    '                             Conservation Act" of 1973.
    '
    'AUTHOR: Peter Straton
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************

    Const ThisFunction As String = "Function CheckDST()"

    Const First As Integer = 1  'First instance in a month
    Const Secnd As Integer = 2  'Second instance in a month
    Const Last  As Integer = 5  'Last instance: use max possible in a month

    Const Mar As Integer = 3, Apr As Integer = 4, Oct As Integer = 10, Nov As Integer = 11

    Const LawYearIdx As Integer = 0, StartInstanceIdx As Integer = 1, StartMonthIdx As Integer = 2, _
          EndInstanceIdx As Integer = 3, EndMonthIdx As Integer = 4

    Dim DateYear As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim StartInstance As Integer, StartMonth As Integer, EndInstance As Integer, EndMonth As Integer
    Static US_StartEndSpecs As Variant

    DateYear = Year(ChkDate)
    If DateYear < 1966 Then
        MsgBox "The specified date, " & ChkDate & ", is prior to this function's minimum date-year (1966) " & _
               "which is necessary due to highly inconsistent use of DST in prior years, over various locales.", _
               vbOKOnly + vbCritical, ThisFunction
        Exit Function  'Return default: False
    End If

    Select Case Locale
    Case "USA", "NN"    'Check these cases first, for execution efficiency and locale-logic shortcut
        If ChkDate >= DateValue("1/6/1974") And ChkDate < DateValue("10/26/1975") Then
            'Non-algorithmic case: On January 4, 1974, President Nixon signed the Emergency Daylight Saving Time
            'Energy Conservation Act of 1973.  Beginning on January 6, 1974, clocks were set ahead. On October 5,
            '1974, Congress amended the Act, and Standard Time returned on October 27, 1974. Daylight Saving Time
            'resumed on February 23, 1975 and ended on October 26, 1975.
            '
            'NOTE: Arizona was exempted.

            If ChkDate >= DateValue("1/6/1974") And ChkDate < DateValue("10/27/1975") Or _
               ChkDate >= DateValue("2/23/1975") And ChkDate < DateValue("10/26/1975") Then

                CheckDST = True
                Exit Function
            End If
        'Else
            'Continue with DST calculation below...
        End If

    Case "UK"   'Check this case next, for execution efficiency and locale-logic shortcut
        If ChkDate >= DateValue("10/27/1968") And ChkDate < DateValue("10/31/1971") Then
            'Non-algorithmic case: The Harold Wilson government adopted "British Standard Time" (actually GMT+1,
            'equivalent to DST) *throughout* the year.  This took place between October 27, 1968 and October 31,
            '1971 when there was a reversion back to the previous arrangement.

            CheckDST = True
            Exit Function   'Return default: False
        'Else
            'Continue with DST calculation below...
        End If

        StartInstance = Last: StartMonth = Mar 'Last Sunday of March
        EndInstance = Last: EndMonth = Oct     'Last Sunday of October

    Case "AZ"
        If DateYear > 1967 Then Exit Function   'Hasn't participated in DST since 1967; return default: False

    Case "AS", "GU", "HI", "MP", "PR", "VI"
        Exit Function  'None of these have participated in DST (since WWII); return default: False

    Case Else
        MsgBox "Unknown Locale specification: """ & Locale & """", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, ThisFunction
    End Select

    If StartInstance = 0 Then '(If not defined above)
        'If necessary, (re)initialize the DST start/end specs by DST law-date lookup table for the USA, then find
        'the DST rule specs that apply, based on the specified date's year vs. the rule start-date years.

        If IsEmpty(US_StartEndSpecs) Then '(Re)init if necessary...
            US_StartEndSpecs = Array(Array(2007, Secnd, Mar, First, Nov), _
                                     Array(1986, First, Mar, Last, Oct), _
                                     Array(1966, Last, Apr, Last, Oct))
        End If
        For i = LBound(US_StartEndSpecs, 1) To UBound(US_StartEndSpecs, 1)
            If DateYear >= US_StartEndSpecs(i)(LawYearIdx) Then Exit For
        Next i
        If i > UBound(US_StartEndSpecs, 1) Then
            Stop 'DEBUG: SHOULD NEVER EXECUTE TO HERE DUE TO ChkDate PARAMETER VALUE CHECK, ABOVE.
            Exit Function
        End If

        StartInstance = US_StartEndSpecs(i)(StartInstanceIdx)   'n-th Sunday of...
        StartMonth = US_StartEndSpecs(i)(StartMonthIdx)         'some month
        EndInstance = US_StartEndSpecs(i)(EndInstanceIdx)       'm-th Sunday of...
        EndMonth = US_StartEndSpecs(i)(EndMonthIdx)             'some other month
    End If

    'Do the DST calculation based on the specifications defined above

    CheckDST = ChkDate >= NthDayOfWeekDate(StartInstance, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, StartMonth, 1)) And _
               ChkDate < NthDayOfWeekDate(EndInstance, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, EndMonth, 1))
End Function 'CheckDST

Public Function CheckDST_UK1972(ChkDate As Date) As Boolean
    '
    'Returns True if the UK "British Summer Time" applies to the specified date, based on the BST system as it's
    'been defined since 1972; otherwise returns False.  Note that this function does not take into account Harold
    'Wilson's experimental "British Standard Time" which took place between October 27, 1968 and October 31, 1971.
    'To correctly handle that date range, use the CheckDST function instead.
    '
    'PARAMETERS:
    '
    '   ChkDate     The date to be checked for DST status.
    '
    'AUTHOR: Peter Straton
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************

    Const Last As Integer = 5   'Last instance: use max possible in a month
    Const Mar As Integer = 3, Oct As Integer = 10
    Dim DateYear As Integer: DateYear = Year(ChkDate)

    CheckDST_UK1972 = ChkDate >= NthDayOfWeekDate(Last, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, Mar, 1)) And _
                      ChkDate < NthDayOfWeekDate(Last, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, Oct, 1))
End Function 'CheckDST_UK1972

Public Function CheckDST_US2007(ChkDate As Date) As Boolean
    '
    'Returns True if the US Federal "Daylight Savings Time" applies to the specified date, based on the DST system
    'established in 2007; otherwise returns False.  Note that this function does not take into account locales
    'such as Arizona, Hawaii or various US protectorates (Puerto Rico, Guam, etc.) so results for those locales
    'will be unreliable.  To correctly handle those locales, use the CheckDST function instead.
    '
    'PARAMETERS:
    '
    '   ChkDate     The date to be checked for DST status.
    '
    'AUTHOR: Peter Straton
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************

    Const First As Integer = 1  'First instance in a month
    Const Secnd As Integer = 2  'Second instance in a month
    Const Mar As Integer = 3, Nov As Integer = 11
    Dim DateYear As Integer: DateYear = Year(ChkDate)

    CheckDST_US2007 = ChkDate >= NthDayOfWeekDate(Secnd, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, Mar, 1)) And _
                      ChkDate < NthDayOfWeekDate(First, vbSunday, DateSerial(DateYear, Nov, 1))
End Function 'CheckDST_US2007

Public Function IsDST(Optional Locale As String = "USA") As Boolean
    '
    'Returns True if Daylight Savings Time is *currently* in effect (in the optionally specified locale);
    'otherwise returns False.
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************

    IsDST = CheckDST(Now(), Locale)
End Function

Function NthDayOfWeekDate(ByVal Instance As Integer, DayOfWeek As Integer, ByVal MonthDate As Date) As Date
    '
    'Returns the Date of the specified Nth instance of the specified day-of-week in the specified month.
    '
    'PARAMETERS:
    '
    '   Instance    The instance-number specified day-of-week in the month.  To get the date of *last* instance in
    '               the month of the specified day-of-week, pass the value 5 as the argument to this parameter.
    '
    '   DayOfWeek   The day-number of the day-of-week for which the Nth instance is to be calculated.  Can be any
    '               of: vbSunday, vbMonday, vbTuesday, vbWednesday, vbThursday, vbFriday, vbSaturday.
    '
    '   MonthDate   The date of the month in which the Nth day-of-week instance is to be calculated.
    '               (e.g. "3/2020" or "3/1/2020")
    '
    'AUTHOR: Peter Straton
    '
    '*************************************************************************************************************

    Instance = IIf(Instance > 5, 5, Instance)   'Max: 5 possible instances

    MonthDate = DateSerial(Year(MonthDate), Month(MonthDate), 1) 'Ensure that it's the first day of the month
    NthDayOfWeekDate = MonthDate + Instance * 7 - Weekday(MonthDate + 7 - DayOfWeek)

    If Month(NthDayOfWeekDate) <> Month(MonthDate) Then NthDayOfWeekDate = NthDayOfWeekDate - 7 '"Last" instance?
End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

A few tweaks to Patrick Honorez's great solution.

A bit of error checking and some extra tests. :-)

```
Option Explicit

'mTimeZones by Patrick Honorez --- www.idevlop.com
'with the precious help of Julian Hess https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510712/78522
'You can reuse but please let all the original comments including this one.

'This modules uses late binding and therefore should not require an explicit reference to Outlook,
'however Outlook must be properly installed and configured on the machine using this module
'Module works with Excel and Access

'Murray Hopkins: a few tweaks for better useability

Private oOutl As Object 'keep Outlook reference active, to save time n recurring calls

Private Function GetOutlook() As Boolean
'get or start an Outlook instance and assign it to oOutl
'returns True if successful, False otherwise
    If oOutl Is Nothing Then
        'Debug.Print "~"
        On Error Resume Next
        Err.Clear
        Set oOutl = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
        If Err.Number Then
            Err.Clear
            Set oOutl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        End If
    End If
    GetOutlook = Not (oOutl Is Nothing)
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Public Function ConvertTime(DT As Date, Optional TZfrom As String = "UTC", Optional TZto As String = "") As Date
'convert datetime with hour from Source time zone to Target time zone
'valid Source & Target time zones can be found in your registry under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows NT/CurrentVersion/Time Zones/
'this version using Outlook, properly handles Dailight Saving Times, including for past and future dates
'it includes a fix for the fact that ConvertTime seems to strip the seconds
'krammy85 2019-01-25 Edit: Outlook rounds minutes when it strips seconds, so modified code to strip seconds (without rounding) prior to running Outlook's ConvertTime.
    Dim TZones As Object
    Dim sourceTZ As Object
    Dim destTZ As Object
    Dim seconds As Single
    Dim DT_SecondsStripped As Date

            ' If the conversion fails it will return the time unchanged
            ' You could change this if you want
    Dim convertedTime As Date
    convertedTime = DT

    If GetOutlook Then
        'fix for ConvertTime stripping the seconds
        seconds = Second(DT) / 86400    'save the seconds as DateTime (86400 = 24*60*60)
        DT_SecondsStripped = DT - seconds
        Set TZones = oOutl.TimeZones

        Set sourceTZ = TZones.item(TZfrom)

        ' Default to the timezone currently on this system if not passed in
        If TZto = "" Then TZto = oOutl.TimeZones.CurrentTimeZone

        Set destTZ = TZones.item(TZto)

        If validTimeZoneName(TZfrom, sourceTZ) And validTimeZoneName(TZto, destTZ) Then
            convertedTime = TZones.ConvertTime(DT_SecondsStripped, sourceTZ, destTZ) + seconds    'add the stripped seconds
        End If
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Could not find MS-Outlook on this computer." & vbCrLf & "It mut be installed for this app to work", vbCritical, "ERROR")
        End
    End If

    ConvertTime = convertedTime
End Function

' Make sure the time zone name returned an entry from the Registry
Private Function validTimeZoneName(tzName, TZ) As Boolean
    Dim nameIsValid As Boolean

    nameIsValid = True

    If TZ Is Nothing Then
        Call MsgBox("The timezone name of '" & tzName & "' is not valid." & vbCrLf & "Please correct it and try again.", vbCritical, "ERROR")

        ' This might be too harsh. ie ends the app.
        ' End
        nameIsValid = False
    End If

    validTimeZoneName = nameIsValid
End Function

' Tests
Public Sub test_ConvertTime()
    Dim t As Date, TZ As String

    t = #8/23/2019 6:15:05 AM#
    Debug.Print "System default", t, ConvertTime(t), Format(t - ConvertTime(t), "h:nn")

    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "AUS Eastern Standard Time")
    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "AUS Central Standard Time")
    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "E. Australia Standard Time")
    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "Aus Central W. Standard Time")
    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "W. Australia Standard Time")
    Call test_DoConvertTime("W. Australia Standard Time", "AUS Eastern Standard Time")

        ' Throw error
    Call test_DoConvertTime("UTC", "Mars Polar Time")

    End
End Sub

Public Sub test_DoConvertTime(ByVal fromTZ As String, ByVal toTZ As String)
    Dim t As Date, TZ As String, resDate As Date, msg

    t = #8/23/2019 6:15:05 AM#
    resDate = ConvertTime(t, fromTZ, toTZ)
    msg = fromTZ & " to " & toTZ
    Debug.Print msg, t, resDate, Format(t - resDate, "h:nn")

End Sub
```

Comment: a function that calls a MsgBox ? Thats is a really bad idea.

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree. Unless you're referring to some code-level instability, the MsgBox idea is exactly what a user would expect. A visible dialog telling them what the problem is and how to resolve it in a way that can't be ignored. End users appreciate the insight, and it wouldn't be a big deal to adapt this to run in non-interactive manner if that's what your experience indicates is the right way to go. But as a general statement? MsgBox >> no MsgBox when it comes to interactive usage.

Comment: Following Neman's thoughts, @iDevlop: Can you elaborate on why you think it is a "really bad idea" please? I am always up for learning something but you haven't offered anything in that regard. :-)

Comment: @Murrah imagine including such a function in an Access query that updates a few hundred (or thousand) records. You will spend hours clicking :-D. There are better ways for error handling. Sale apples on Excel: use that in a long list and user will get mad at every recalc.

Comment: @iDevelop: Thanks, and yes, of course that would be an unhelpful way of using the function. In my case there was only one instance and telling the user right then was the most helpful thing to do. As always, context is everything! Thanks again for elaborating on your thoughts. Go well, Murray