# Excel Help: formatting datetime with timezone

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use an Excel file to track certain orders. The file only consists of 3 columns currently. One for the order number, one for a comment and an automated column that populates a timestamp whenever a user enters a new order. I'm needing to add the time zone to the timestamp, but can't seem to find a solution.

This file is stored in a box folder online for ease of access. We have multiple people across the US that will be using this file. Everything currently works except when using Excel Online. The timestamp does not populate when using Excel Online, but the main issue I'm having is trying to add the time zone. We have specific cutoffs for orders in CST. If we have a user that enters an order in PST it will currently look like they put in their order by cutoff, when really they didn't.

My VBA code for the DateTime is:

```
If Target.Column = Range("DOcol").Column Then
        Range("DateCol").Rows(Target.Row) = Now()
    
    End If
```

And currently formatted as: mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Here is what the structure looks like.
[image]

Comment: How do you know the timezone of the user?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39580145/478884

Comment: For this instance, I was video chatting them and I knew they were in PST when they inputted the data a 7:58am PST, I followed up the call by adding 2 more tests here in CST minutes later in CST per the screen shot above.

Comment: Sorry I meant "how would your code know" ?

Comment: I assumed the now() function took the timestamp of the computer you are using which is configured to your correct time zone, but apparently it just looks at the time, and not the full timestamp

Comment: Your best bet would be to edit your VBA to add a timestamp using a fixed timezone (eg. PST)  Some options here about how to get there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1600875/how-to-get-the-current-datetime-in-utc-from-an-excel-vba-macro or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120915/get-timezone-information-in-vba-excel