# How to convert UTC to PDT in excel using formula

Tags: excel, utc

I have a file from amazon and in that they are providing datetime in UTC format.Below is the example of that :

> 2020-06-15T23:59:56+00:00

Now I want convert this datetime into PDT format in Excel using formula. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Do all the datetimes end in `+00:00`?

Comment: Did you try to build a solution based on the info you can find here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120915/get-timezone-information-in-vba-excel  ?

Comment: @BigBen Yes all datetimes end in `+00:00`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like below. It works in 3 parts :

1. Substitute "T" from the value with a space.
2. Take only left part of value for 19 characters that make up the relevant date and time
3. Deduct 7 hours using 7/24 from the time as PDT = UTC - 7 hours

`=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"T"," "),19) - 7/24`

[image]

Comment: I am getting `43997.70829` after applying above formula

Comment: Change the format pf the cell to date time. Format 》 custom 》 yyyy-mm--dd hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 2):

Use `SUBSTITUTE`, and then subtract `7/24` to subtract 7 hours.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"T"," "),"+00:00","")-7/24
```

[image]

Comment: Why should time be '00:00' ? (see answer from @VarunT)

Comment: @BigBen after applying above formula i am getting `43997.70829` value

Comment: That's because you need to apply the date/time format to the cell. Date/times are just *numbers*.